# EF 5.0 - Can't make bi-directional relationship work with Code First

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a class called WidgetCollection.  It has an Items property exposing a List(Of Widget) and a SelectedWidget property.  I would expect EF to build the database as follows:

- Add a WidgetCollection_Id property in my Widgets table, specifying
  which WidgetCollection each widget is in
- Add a SelectedWidget_Id property in my WidgetCollection table, specifying which of the
  Widgets is selected
- Add a 1-to-many relationship from WidgetCollection.Id to Widget.WidgetCollection_Id
- Add a 1-to-0-or-1 relationship from Widget.Id to WidgetCollection.SelectedWidget_Id

I can confirm that it does appear to build the database schema correctly, however I get the following error if I ever save the context after assigning to SelectedWidget:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException occurred
>     HResult=-2146233087
>     Message=An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key > properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types.

With an inner exception of

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

I can prevent this error by never assigning WidgetCollect.SelectedWidget.

I guess the problem is that EF can't work out what to do with relationships in both directions, but I just can't find a way to point it in the right direction.  Example code follows, all suggestions welcome!

```vb
Public Class Widget
    Private miId As Integer
    Public Property Id As Integer
        Get
            Return miId
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            miId = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private msName As String
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return msName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            msName = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
Public Class WidgetCollection
    Private miId As Integer
    Public Property Id As Integer
        Get
            Return miId
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            miId = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private msName As String
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return msName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            msName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private moSelectedWidget
    Public Property SelectedWidget As Widget
        Get
            Return moSelectedWidget
        End Get
        Set(value As Widget)
            moSelectedWidget = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private moWidgets As New List(Of Widget)
    Public Property Widgets As List(Of Widget)
        Get
            Return moWidgets
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Widget))
            moWidgets = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class MyContext
    Inherits DbContext
    Public Property Widgets As DbSet(Of Widget)
    Public Property WidgetCollections As DbSet(Of WidgetCollection)
End Class

Class Application
    Public Sub New()
        Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = New SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", "", "Data Source=\EFtest.sdf")
        Database.SetInitializer(New DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(Of MyContext))
        Dim oContext = New MyContext

        Dim oWidgetA = New Widget With {.Name = "Widget A"}
        Dim oWidgetB = New Widget With {.Name = "Widget A"}
        Dim oWidgetCollection = New WidgetCollection With {.Name = "My widget collection"}
        oWidgetCollection.Widgets.Add(oWidgetA)
        oWidgetCollection.Widgets.Add(oWidgetB)
        oWidgetCollection.SelectedWidget = oWidgetA  'Removing this line prevents error

        oContext.WidgetCollections.Add(oWidgetCollection)
        oContext.SaveChanges()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the exception means what it says:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.

These two lines...

```
oWidgetCollection.Widgets.Add(oWidgetA)
oWidgetCollection.SelectedWidget = oWidgetA
```

...mean that EF must store the `oWidgetCollection` before it can set the `WidgetCollection_Id` foreign key in `oWidgetA`, but the second line requires to store the objects the other way around, namely that `oWidgetA` must be stored before EF can set the foreign key `SelectedWidget_Id` in `oWidgetCollection`.

To resolve the conflict I believe you must save the changes twice:

```
oWidgetCollection.Widgets.Add(oWidgetA)
oWidgetCollection.Widgets.Add(oWidgetB)

oContext.WidgetCollections.Add(oWidgetCollection)
oContext.SaveChanges()

oWidgetCollection.SelectedWidget = oWidgetA
oContext.SaveChanges()
```

By the way: This expectation...

> Add a 1-to-0-or-1 relationship from Widget.Id to WidgetCollection.SelectedWidget_Id

...is not correct. EF will create another one-to-many relationship, i.e. the same `SelectedWidget` can be selected for many `WidgetCollection`s. The default relationship EF will create by convention when you have navigation properties only on one side of the relationship is always one-to-many. You need data annotations or Fluent API to override this default behaviour.

I suggest to leave this relationship as one-to-many. One-to-one relationships are more difficult and EF only supports one-to-one relationships with shared primary keys which would mean that you can't select different widgets as selected. The only possible selected widget would be the one with the same primary key value that also the WidgetCollection has.

Comment: Although I'd tried that in my original project, I didn't try it in my example project, so incorrectly assumed the error I was reproducing had the same cause.

It turns out that the real problem in my original project was in the property getter from my collection's ID.  A stupid problem, yes, but also a counter-intuitive error message.

Thanks for the push in the right direction!